# QuestDB stopped working after update to 6.0.3 on homebrew

Tags: questdb

After updating QuestDB to 6.0.3 using homebrew I cannot start it anymore

```
$ questdb start
  ___                  _   ____  ____
 / _ \ _   _  ___  ___| |_|  _ \| __ )
| | | | | | |/ _ \/ __| __| | | |  _ \
| |_| | |_| |  __/\__ \ |_| |_| | |_) |
 \__\_\\__,_|\___||___/\__|____/|____/
                        www.questdb.io
JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0.9-1.el7_9.x86_64//bin/java
QuestDB server 6.0.3
Copyright (C) 2014-2021, all rights reserved.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libquestdb16783513652948944750.so: /tmp/libquestdb16783513652948944750.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
    at io.questdb@6.0.3/io.questdb.std.Os.loadLib(Os.java:161)
    at io.questdb@6.0.3/io.questdb.std.Os.<clinit>(Os.java:179)
    at io.questdb@6.0.3/io.questdb.ServerMain.<init>(ServerMain.java:98)
    at io.questdb@6.0.3/io.questdb.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:259)
```

I'm using homebrew on CentOS Linux. Anyone have seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is permissions on `/tmp` directory even though error does not say anything about it. QuestDB is Java and Java uses hardcoded `/tmp` as temp directory on Linux and does not try to use any environment variables to override it. QuestDB tries to load native binary and java uses `/tmp' to unpack and load it from.

The only solution is to add exec permissions to '/tmp' directory to the account which runs QuestDB.